# Python tornado, gives an error inside open()

Tags: websocket, tornado

I'm implementing a web socket server with tornado (currently version 3.1).

Inside the `open()` function I check GET argument, then based on it - I want to raise an error.

Something like this:

```
def open(self):
   token = self.get_argument('token')
   if ...:
      ??? # raise an error
```

How do I raise an error inside the open function? I did not find the way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just raise an exception like you normally would:

```
class EchoWebSocket(websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self):
        if some_error:
            raise Exception("Some error occurred")
```

Tornado will abort the connection when an unhandled exception occurs in `open`. Here's how `open` is scheduled to run in the tornado source:

```
    self._run_callback(self.handler.open, *self.handler.open_args,
                       **self.handler.open_kwargs)
```

Here is `_run_callback`:

```
def _run_callback(self, callback, *args, **kwargs):
    """Runs the given callback with exception handling.

    On error, aborts the websocket connection and returns False.
    """
    try:
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception:
        app_log.error("Uncaught exception in %s",
                      self.request.path, exc_info=True)
        self._abort()

def _abort(self):
    """Instantly aborts the WebSocket connection by closing the socket"""
    self.client_terminated = True
    self.server_terminated = True
    self.stream.close()  # forcibly tear down the connection
    self.close()  # let the subclass cleanup
```

As you can see, it aborts the connection when an exception occurs.